# Form result are integers and not string value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've used this piece of code and created arrays:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var json = {
    "Merk": ["Model - Kies eerst een merk"],
    "Abarth": ["500","500C","Punto"],
    "Alfa Romeo": ["159 Sportwagon","Giulietta","MiTo",],
    "Aston Martin": ["Cygnet","DB9 Coupe","DB9 Volante","Rapide","V12Vantage Coupe","V12Vantage Roadster","V8Vantage Coupe","V8Vantage Roadster","Vanquish"],
    "Audi": ["A1","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","Q3","Q5","Q7","R8","RS4","RS5","S4","S5","S6","S7","S8","SQ5","TT"],
    "BMW": ["1 Serie","3 Serie","5 Serie","6 Serie","7 Serie","X1","X3","X5","X6","Z4"],
    "Bentley": ["Continental GT","Continental GTC","Flying Spur"],
    "Chevrolet": ["Aveo","Camaro","Captiva","Corvette","Cruze","Orlando","Spark","Trax","Volt"],
    "Citroën": ["Berlingo","C-Zero","C1","C3","C3 Picasso","C4","C4 Aircross","C4 Picasso","C5 Sedan","C5 Tourer","C6","C8","DS3","DS3 Cabrio","DS4","DS5","Grand C4 Picasso","Nemo",],"Dacia": ["Duster","Lodgy","Sandero","SanderoStepway"],
    "Ferrari": ["458","California","F12","FF"],
    "Fiat": ["500","Bravo","Doblo","Panda","Punto","Qubo","Sedici"],
    "Fisker": ["Karma"],
    "Ford": ["B-Max","C-Max","Fiesta","Focus","Galaxy","Grand C","KA","Kuga","Mondeo","S-Max"],
    "Honda": ["Accord","Accord Tourer","CR-V","CR-Z","Civic","Insight","Jazz","Jazz Hybrid"],
    "Hyundai": ["Genesis","Santa Fe","Veloster","i10","i20","i30","i40","ix20","ix35"],
    "Infiniti": ["EX","FX","G","M"],
    "Jaguar": ["F-Type","XF","XF Sportbrake","XJ Series","XK","XKR"],
    "Jeep": ["Compass","Grand Cherokee","Wrangler","Wrangler Unlimited"],
    "Kia": ["Carens","Cee'd","Cee'd Sportswagon","Optima","Picanto","Pro Cee´d","Rio","Sorento","Soul","Sportage","Venga"],
    "Lamborghini": ["Aventador","Gallardo"],
    "Lancia": ["Delta","Flavia","Thema","Voyager","Ypsilon"],
    "Land Rover": ["Defender","Discovery","Freelander","Range Rover","Range Rover Evoque","Range Rover Sport"],
    "Lexus": ["CT","GS","IS","IS250C","LS 600h","RX"],
    "Lotus": ["Elise","Evora","Exige"],
    "Maserati": ["GranCabrio","GranTurismo","Quattroporte"],
    "Maybach": ["Maybach"],
    "Mazda": ["CX-5","MX-5","Mazda2","Mazda3","Mazda5","Mazda6","Mazda6 Sportbreak"],
    "Mercedes Benz": ["A-Klasse","B-Klasse","C-Klasse","CL-Klasse","CLA-Klasse","CLS-Klasse","E-Klasse","G-Klasse","GL-Klasse","GLK-Klasse","M-Klasse","S-Klasse","SL-Klasse","SLK-Klasse","SLS AMG","Viano"],
    "Mini": ["Cabrio","Clubman","Countryman","Coupé","Mini","Paceman","Roadster"],
    "Mitsubishi": ["ASX","ColtCZ5","Lancer Sportback","Outlander","Pajero","SpaceStar","i-MiEV"],
    "Nissan": ["370Z","EVALIA","GT-R","Juke","Leaf","Micra","Murano","Note","Pathfinder","Pixo","Qashqai","Qashqai + 2","X-Trail"],
    "Opel": ["ADAM","Agila","Ampera","Astra","Cascada","Combo","Corsa","Insignia","Meriva","Mokka","Zafira"],
    "Peugeot": ["107","2008","207","208","3008","308","5008","508","807","Bipper Tepee","Partner Tepee","RCZ","iOn"],
    "Porsche": ["911","911 Cabriolet","Boxster","Cayenne","Cayman","Panamera"],
    "Renault": ["Clio","Clio Estate","Fluence","Grand Espace","Grand Kangoo Family","Grand Scénic","Kangoo Family","Laguna","Laguna Estate","Megane","Megane Coupé","Megane Estate","Scénic","Twingo","ZOE"],
    "Seat": ["Alhambra","Altea","Altea Freetrack","Altea XL","Exeo","Ibiza","Leon","Mii","Toledo"],
    "Skoda": ["Citigo","Fabia","Fabia Combi","Octavia","Octavia Combi","Rapid","Roomster","Superb","Superb Combi","Yeti"],
    "Smart": ["Fortwo cabrio","Fortwo coupe"],
    "SsangYong": ["Actyon Sports","Korando","Rexton"],
    "Subaru": ["BRZ","Forester","Legacy Outback","Legacy Touring Wagon","Trezia","WRX STI","XV"],
    "Suzuki": ["Alto","Grand Vitara","Jimny","Kizashi","SX4","Splash","Swift"],
    "Tesla": ["Model S"],
    "Toyota": ["Auris","Auris Touring Sports","Avensis Sedan","Avensis Wagon","Aygo","GT86","IQ","Landcruiser","Landcruiser V8","Prius","Prius Wagon","RAV4","Verso","Verso-S","Yaris"],
    "Volkswagen": ["Beetle","CC","Caddy","Golf","Jetta","Multivan","Passat","Phaeton","Polo","Sharan","Tiguan","Touareg","Touran","up!"],
    "Volvo": ["C70","S60","S80","V40","V40 Cross Country","V60","V70","XC60","XC70","XC90"]
  };

  function carMake () {
    select = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
    select.options.length = 0;
    for(make in json) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(make, make);
    }
}

function carModel(sel) {
    var car_make = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value
    select = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
    select.options.length = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<json[car_make].length;i++) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(json[car_make][i], i);
    }
  }
</script>
```

It populates my dropdowns and selecting the make will give me models to choose from. The form returns the full name string for the car make. But for model it returns an integer. corresponding with the place in the array.

I need BMW to be stored as the car make
and
X5 to be stored as "X5" and not as 8

How can I improve this?

Comment: FYI, your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON. The variable you named `json` holds an object as value. JSON is a data-exchange format, like XML, CSV or YAML.

Comment: You need to show the code of how the dropdowns are populated, which is where I suspect the issue may be.

Comment: @ptutt: It's at the bottom of the code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are passing `i` as second argument to `Option` (`new Option(json[car_make][i], i)`), so the value of the counter becomes the value of the option. If you want the actual array element to be the value, pass it instead:

```
new Option(json[car_make][i], json[car_make][i]);
```

Or since the text and value are the same, simply omit the second argument:

```
new Option(json[car_make][i]);
```

(the same goes for `new Option(make, make)`, you can just use `new Option(make)`)

If an `option` element does not explicitly have a value, its inner text becomes the value.

Comment: Thanks Felix! That was it... *duh* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How are you populating your dropdowns? I imagine it might look something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Model 1<option>
    <option value="2">Model 2<option>
<select>
```

The thing is, if there's an integer in the value attribute of the option tags, you're going to get that integer regardless of what the text says. So for example, here if I selected Model 2, the value of the form is still 2.

It all just depends on how you're creating these drop downs!